# Which poker hand is this?

Tags: probability, hand

[image]

How's Ruane winning with 100%?

He has no straight or full house or flush, while Hallaert has a pair.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfeit_(poker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each players' hand is comprised of their best 5 card hand...

Ruane has Two Pair: Queens and Tens with a King kicker

Hallaert has Two Pair: Queens and Tens with a 6 Kicker

Ruane wins with the higher kicker.